# Find good next pair for comparison based total ranking

Tags: algorithms, ranking, paired-comparisons, order-statistics

I want to obtain a total ranking from pairwise binary comparisons. For this, I can use algorithms like [Balanced Rank Estimation](http://www.jmlr.org/proceedings/papers/v28/wauthier13.pdf) or [Bradley-Terry Model](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/131270/48218). However, I wonder if you need fewer comparisons, if the compared pairs are chosen cleverly. So rather than having a complete set of comparison results, we compute the next comparison for the participant on the fly.

The algorithm I'm looking for estimates a ranking that eventually converges. After each comparison, the estimate is improved and a meaningful new comparison pair is suggested, to help the algorithm to converge as fast as possible.

Which algorithm can I use for this task?

**Update**

I found a [talk of Wiki Surveys creator Matthew Salganik](https://vimeo.com/51369546#t=17m47s) talking about my question. He refers to a *formal way of defining what's the pair that likely will give you the most information*. Unfortunately, I couldn't find an algorithm or paper on this. How are those kinds of statistical models called and how can I find out more about them?